# How do I have a Tkinter GUI have a button that appears as a picture?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I make a Tkinter GUI with a button that appears as a picture?

Current code looks a bit like this:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def Cookie():
    global globcookies
    global CookieValue
    global globMultiply
    global globUser
    global globLoggedIn
    CookieValue = 1 * globMultiply
    globcookies = globcookies + CookieValue
    print("Cookies =",globcookies)
    Info()
    Line()
    if globLoggedIn == "true":
        SaveData()

Button(master, text='Click!', command=Cookie).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it very simple and you would have found it with a bit of googeling:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="*your image file*")
Button(master, command=Cookie, image=photo).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
```